# How can I allow the user to purchase more than one of an item?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a more complex version of the program codecademy has you write as part of the python lesson plan. Originally, you can create a "shopping_list" to use as an argument when running the compute_bill() function. The function itself adds up the prices of the items you chose to give you your total. You can't, however, choose a quantity of more than one of any item. This is what I tried to give the program the ability to do.

This is the original code:

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

# Write your code below!

def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0 
    for x in food:
        if stock[x] > 0:
            total += prices[x]
            stock[x] -= 1
    return total

print compute_bill(shopping_list)
```

This returns "5.5" since it added up the prices for the banana, orange, and apple.

This is the code I tried to write, to ask the user what items they wanted and how much of each item:

```
import sys

print "use q as an input for any question to leave the program"

stock = {"orange": 15, "apple": 20, "pear": 14, "cigarettes": 18}

price = {"orange": 2.50, "apple": 2.65, "pear": 2.80, "cigarettes": 100}

for x in price:
    print [str(x)]
    print "Costs %r." % price[x]
    print "We have %r in stock." % stock[x]
    print "\n"*1



def run():
    q = "q"
    while True: #Asking the user what they want.
        try:
            items = raw_input("Enter what you'd like to buy >").split(", ") 
            if items == "q" or ['q']:
                return

            if isinstance(items,(int, long, float, complex))== True or \
            isinstance(items,stock[x])== False:
                print """Looks like you've entered an invalid format.
                Type the items you wish in list
                form: ["1","2","3",] naming products from the store"""

            if isinstance(items,stock[x])== True:
                items = food
                print "Great, now for the quantity!"
                break
            else:
                print "That's not a valid choice."
                continue
        except TypeError:
            print "Looks like you've entered an invalid format."        
            continue

    while True: #asking how much of the items
        try:
            quantity = raw_input("How many of each item do you want to buy?>").split(", ")
            if quanity == "q" or ['q']:
                return
            elif isinstance(quantity, str)== True:
                print "Looks like you've entered an invalid format."
                continue
            elif isinstance(quantity,str)== False and stock[x]== True:
                quantity = number
                print "Great, let's calculate your purchase now."
                break           
            else:
                print "That's not a valid choice."
                continue
        except TypeError:
            print "Looks like you've entered an invalid format."
            continue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()

def compute_bill(food,number): #calculate the bill
    total = 0
    for x in food:
        if isinstance(food, basestring)== True and stock[x] > 0 and number == 1:
            total = total+ price[x]
            stock[x] = stock[x]-1                       
            return total
        elif ValueError:
            print "Use a number for number!"    
        elif TypeError:
            print "Use a number for number!"

    for y in number:
        if isinstance(number, int)== True and stock[x] > 0 and number > 1:
            total+= number[y]*price[x]
            stock[x] = stock[x]-number[y]
            return total    
        elif stock[x] == 0:
            print "Sorry, sold out"
        else:
            print "Invalid choice. Please try again."

print "\n"*2
```

When I run the program it says "Enter what you'd like to buy >", I enter "apple, cigarettes" without quotations and it just quits the program. This is my first attempt at writing a program, or at least adding on to one so it's extremely buggy. At one point I had it asking me the next question but I could tell it wasn't doing what I wanted with the input whatsoever since the program was unable to give me any sort of numerical answer.

Comment: Actually, the original code does, in fact, allow you to have multiple of the same item - by putting it in the shopping_list more than once, eg. `shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple", "banana"]`

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that, but if someone wanted to buy 15 bananas it would be highly inconvenient to have to type that out 15 times along with the rest of the items their shopping list. I want to be able to ask the user what quantity they want and have them input a number then have the program multiply that number with the price of the item.

Comment: You should reexamine your line:
`if quanity == "q" or ['q']:`
and related. The second part of it, namely the `or ['q']` bit... you're comparing the truth value of the list that contains one element q. Since it is a non-empty list, it is always true.

If you wanted to check whether any of the inputs that a person had entered were 'q', a much better way would be to `if 'q' in items:`, or if you want to make sure that 'q' is the _only_ element in the list, you could do `if list == ['q']`.

Answer (score 0):

First strip all whitespace from the split items.

Also use `terms.lower().split()` to ensure that capital letters do no cause errors.

You have an error in this line

```
if isinstance(items,(int, long, float, complex))== True or \
        isinstance(items,stock[x])== False:
```

Notice that in the function run you do not define x. This will cause a failure when you try to execute

```
isinstance(items,stock[x])== False:
```

You should not need to check the type, especially since items is built from raw_input and is a list of strings. You can test if each member of item is in stock using the code below. I carefully made it a separate set of for loops for ease of reading. You can do it more efficiently with list comprehension. Since you do not have numbers or anything else in stock, that is all you need to check.

```
for ix in items:
    i = ix.strip() # remove leading and trailing blanks
    if i in stock:
        print "Item ", i, " has ", stock[i], "available."
    else:
        print "No items of ", i, " available"
```

If something is not in stock, it will have no price (use price.get(i, 0) to make something not in stock have a default price of 0).

Note that this uses the previous method of asking for one of each item and subtracting one from the available count. You can ask for multiples of each item.  One way is to make items a dictionary with the number requested as the value and the item name the key. Then just put the appropriate code into the items loop.

```
totprice = 0
# Note that items already used lower
for i in items:
    # Build the dictionaries with strip() to remove blanks
    avail = stock.get(i, 0) # This is a number
    each = price.get(i, 0) # this is a number
    req = items.get(i, 0).lower()  # this is a number
    if req > avail:
        print "Not enough items available, get ", avail
        req = avail
    total = req*each
    print "There are ", avail, "available of item", i
    print "Item ", i, "costs ",  each
    print req, " items requested"
    print "Total cost of item ", i, " is ", total
    totprice += total
    if avail > 0
        stock[i] -= req
print "Total price for all items is: ", totprice
```

This will automatically skip any invalid inputs without special testing.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about the .get() function yet. How would I go about stripping all the white space from the split items though?

Comment: @Jason_Silva Since each item is a string object use string.strip() to remove the whitespace from each string object. Thus after the split (on ',') you would have " apples" in the string i.strip() changes it to 'apples'

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the statement `if items == "q" or ['q']`. This evaluates `items == "q"` as well as `['q']`. Since

```
>>> bool(['q'])
True
>>>
```

Your `if` statement will pass to the `return` every time. Instead, just check `if items[0] == "q"`.

---